# How do I correctly pluralize acronyms?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)
>   [Plural form of the acronym LASER](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20603/plural-form-of-the-acronym-laser)

I was just writing an email asking a supervisor about downloading multiple dynamic-link library files. The acronym for these is DLL, and the full spelling, *dynamic-link library*, is never used. How would this be pluralized, because normally I would just add an s, but *DLLs* is difficult to understand. Sometimes I add an apostrophe to make it *DLL's*, but I know this isn't grammatically correct. So my question is, how do I make the acronym *DLL* (and acronyms in general) plural?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"DLLs" is fine. Just capitalize the acronym (it's actually an initialism which makes capitalization even more appropriate/necessary) but leave the plural letters lowercase.

Answer (score 5):

When I reffer to .dll files (or any file extension), I usually add "files" after to avoid confusion as to what a .dll is.

And I add a period before because .dll is a file type.

Just my own convention that works for me.